# VIM: Read "variable" from current directory / project

Tags: vim, pylint, flake8

So in my .vimrc I have this:

```
let g:syntastic_python_pylint_post_args="--max-line-length=80"
```

I want to have something like:

```
let g:syntastic_python_pylint_post_args="$(cat .line_length.txt)"
```

And I want this `cat` command to run whenever I open vim.

For example if I have a file in a project

```
myproject/.line_length.txt
```

And the contents of the .line_length.txt is `120` for example and I run

```
vim
```

inside that directory, it should read that file and set the contents of the file to the variable.

...

Is this possible somehow?

I have tried using project specific .vimrc files but it does not seem to read

```
let g:syntastic_python_pylint_post_args="--max-line-length=120"
```

It will read `set ...` lines though, but not `let g: ...` lines.

Answer (score 3):

A literal translation of your attempted `$(...)` syntax would be this:

```
let g:syntastic_python_pylint_post_args = substitute(system('cat .line_length.txt'), '\n\+$', '', '')
```

But there's actually no need to run an external command for this. Vim has the low-level [`:help readfile()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#readfile%28%29) function:

```
let g:syntastic_python_pylint_post_args = readfile('.line_length.txt')[0]
```

#### Caveats

- Depending on the location you start Vim in, the configuration may not exist. You need to account for that, probably using a `filereadable()` conditional around it, or just ignoring any errors with `:silent!`.
- Some plugins only read their configuration variables during startup, and after that ignore any changes to it. This should be fine for your plan to run in `~/.vimrc`, but it may affect your ability to "reload" a different project during runtime (see below).

## Refresher on local configuration

Your solution depends on Vim being started inside the "project directory". You've also mentioned project-specific vimrc as an alternative. Here are some options for that:

### Central configuration

If it's okay to configure the specific commands / local exceptions centrally, you can put such autocmds into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile /path/to/dir/* setlocal ts=4 sw=4
```

It is important to use `:setlocal` instead of `:set`, and likewise `:map <buffer> ...` and `:command! -buffer ...`.

On the other hand, if you want the specific configuration stored with the project (and don't want to embed this in all files via *modelines*), you have the following two options:

### Local config with built-in functionality

If you always start Vim from the project root directory, the built-in

```
:set exrc
```

enables the reading of a `.vimrc` file from the current directory. You can place the `:set ts=4 sw=4` commands in there.

### Local config through plugin

Otherwise, you need the help of a plugin; there are several on vim.org; I can recommend the [localrc plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393) (especially with [my own enhancements](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-localrc/tree/enhancements)), which even allows local filetype-specific configuration.

<sup>Note that reading configuration from the file system has security implications; you may want to `:set secure`.</sup>

Comment: Or just put whatever project-specific options you need in a [`.pylintrc`](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/run.html?highlight=pylintrc) file. This is why I discourage people to go to [so] for help with syntastic: they should try to understand what they're doing instead of making random changes and hoping for the best. Of course, your solution works too, but you brought a cannon to kill a fly. _shrug_